# SSL with MySQL Doctrine and Symfony4

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have been trying to add SSL to a remote sql database in doctrine/Symfony.

here is my doctrine yaml so far

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    # configure these for your database server
    driver: 'pdo_sql'
    server_version: '5.7'
    charset: utf8mb4
    default_table_options:
        charset: utf8mb4
        collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

    url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    options:
        !php/const:PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA: '%env(ca_cert)%'
        !php/const:PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY : '%env(private_key)%'
        !php/const:PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT : '%env(public_cert)%'
        !php/const:PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT : false
```

The problem is it works fine from console when I run php bin/console doctrine:schema:update but I  get access denied (database error) when I try to access the web app from the browser. It works as expected when I use an account that doesn't require ssl encryption.

Is there something  I am missing?

Comment: Always strange that you figure it out after asking the question. It was a permission issue. Works now after giving www-data read and execute (5) permissions to the folder where the certificates were stored.  Leaving this here in case it'd help someone else